# jquery infinite loop after function is made

Tags: jquery, loops, infinite-loop, infinite

I have a function that rotates various ads by fading in and out, but i need it to loop infinitely until someone clicks on one of the images. Here is the function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    /* thumbnail ads */
    $('#adthumb1').delay(3500).fadeIn(1500).delay(9000).fadeOut(1500);
    $('#adthumb2').fadeIn(0000).delay(3500).fadeOut(1500).delay(2000).fadeIn(1500);
    $('#adthumb3').fadeIn(0000).delay(7000).fadeOut(1500).delay(2000).fadeIn(1500);
    $('#adthumb4').fadeIn(0000).delay(10500).fadeOut(1500).delay(2000).fadeIn(1500);
    /* main ads */
    $('#mainad1').fadeIn(0000).delay(3500).fadeOut(1500);
    $('#mainad2').delay(3500).fadeIn(1500);
    $('#mainad3').delay(7000).fadeIn(1500);
    $('#mainad4').delay(10500).fadeIn(1500);
});
```

Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: Why don't you just build an array of your elements and then use the callback of .fadeIn() or .fadeOut() to cycle them?

Comment: I want some of the animations to overlap slightly and from what i understand, callbacks would wait for each animation to complete, correct me if im wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval), capture the intervalID, and use [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.clearInterval) to cancel the loop in a click handler on the div containing the rotating ads.